# AspNetCore - Array on QueryString BadRequest

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple httpGet endpoint that receive a string

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpGet("filter/{filters}"), Route("filter")]
    public virtual IActionResult Filter(string filters)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(Service.GetByFilter(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FilterHelper>(filters)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogWarning(LoggingEvents.GET_ENTITY_BY_FILTER, ex, Localizer["EntityGetFilterFailed"]);
            return Ok(new RequestResult(StatusResult.Danger, new Message(string.Format(Localizer["UnexpectedError"], LoggingEvents.GET_ENTITY_BY_FILTER))));
        }
    }
```

Yesterday, it was working fine, today my PC fails on boot and is been restored, after that my API is giving me bad request results.

If I call this url

```
http://localhost:23272/api/users/filter?filters={"Page":1,"PageSize":5}
```

The request works correct, but if I try to call this url ( which works earlier )

```
http://localhost:23272/api/users/filter?filters={"Page":1,"PageSize":5, "FilterItens": []}
```

The API send me back a BadRequest status (400). Already tried to pass the array with some itens, badrequest too.

Any ideias on how to handle that ?

Detail: If I call from Postman, it works correct.

```
http://localhost:23272/api/users/filter?filters={"Page":1,"PageSize":5, "FilterItens": []}
```

My model

```
public class FilterHelper
{
    #region Properties
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FilterItem> FilterItens { get; set; }
    public string[] Includes { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you don't show your model, its more likely you have a typo => `FilterItens` should probably be `FilterItems`. But be aware, HTTP has no concept of "arrays", it is only interpreted by the server. i.e. `?q=1&q=2` is just sent as 2 q values. It's not an array. Same for `?q[]=1&q[]=2`. Only the server (i.e PHP, .NET, ASP.NET, python, ruby) interprets how this value are treated: `?q=1&q=2` could be treated as "only take last" or "only take first" or "treat multiple values as array". The used framework decides that, **not** HTTP Specification

Comment: Its not a typo, i'm recieving the model as a "string", the api gives me back that error before the conversion. Edited with my model

Comment: @Tseng I'm trying to send "{"Page":1,"PageSize":5, "FilterItens": []}" as a string to my API and then render it on the server.

If I send that with postman, it works correct, If I send with angular, it brokes

Comment: First, see the updated comment. Second, passing data like this to the controller will fail as soon as you have an `=`, `&` or `?`, because `&` is treated as parameter separator, and `=`as parameter assignment. If you pass parameters to query, you **ALWAYS** have to escape them, especially `&` and `=` however from the Firefox Window I can (In ASP.NET Via `Uri.EscapeDataString(...)`. Dunno the one for JS or if it escapes correctly there too, you gotta to watch at the raw request and not on the FF view

Comment: I will not have an ```=``` in the string, and, like I sad, if I issue a get via postman it works correct, I just can't figure out why it isn't working from my app

Comment: It doesn't answer my question whether its escaped or not. You should always URL escape the parameters, i.e. `= ` turns into  `%3D`, and `&` into `%26` etc. `http://localhost:23272/api/users/filter?filters={"Page":1,"PageSize":5}` must be passed (in raw http request) as `http://localhost:23272/api/users/filter?filters=%7B%22Page%22%3A1,%22PageSize%22%3A5%7D`. Whether your framework does that or if you have to do that manually, its not for me to decide. If the parameters are **not escaped** you will receive an undefined behavior which could be **anything**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148097/discussion-between-lucas-freitas-and-tseng).

Comment: How is your Route Look Like ? I have small doubt regarding your working url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem was:

**My Authorization token was too large for the request header.**

The token length was with about 16k length and was broking the header.

I made a change to the token and It finished with 800 length, everything Works again.